# How to work with SlidingMenu library

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu, sliding

I am using the [SlidingMenu][1] Library in my App and have made a menu but I am not sure how to customize this.

First, the Up Navigation button on the action bar does not pull up the menu. It just does not do anything when clicked. The menu works by sliding in anywhere on the screen but not with that button.

Also, is there a way to change that up navigation '<' icon and make it work like Google + or others with the animation of the three horizontal lines?

My code is as follows:

```
public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    private int mTitleRes;
    protected ListFragment mFrag;

    public BaseActivity(int titleRes) {
        mTitleRes = titleRes;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(mTitleRes);

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFrag = new MenuListFragment();
            t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
            t.commit();
        } else {
            mFrag = (ListFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);
        }

        // customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

And the main activity:

```
public class StatusActivity extends BaseActivity {

    public StatusActivity() {
        super(R.string.title_status_page);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);

        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
..
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        getSlidingMenu().showContent();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution on this: <<Also, is there a way to change that up navigation '<' icon and make it work like Google + or others with the animation of the three horizontal lines?>> ? Thanks.